# out of memory while loading model weights using CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

1.I have trained my deep learning model on GPU using

```
import keras    
model.save('trained_model.h5')
```

2. And I want to load the model and predict on CPU using

   model = load_model('trained_model.h5')

But got the following errors

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: CUDA runtime implicit initialization on GPU:0 failed. Status: out of memory
```

How I can load the trained model on CPU?

Comment: I don't think the question has enough information to solve the issue. try (1) rebooting the computer/closing other programs (2) specify the amount of ram/GPU you have, and the size of the model.

Comment: It's also possible that there literally isn't enough memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error code you got is saying your GPU is out of memory. To run on CPU, you need to put in

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=""
```

in the terminal or in the code would be

```
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
```